Images and thumbnails are not displayed; only the preloaded data is shown
I'm having an issue with Drupal 10 where the images and thumbnails are not displaying correctly. When I upload images, only the preload data is visible, as shown in the attached screenshots.
When I upload images to my site, instead of seeing the actual images or thumbnails, I only see the preload data.
I've checked the file permissions and ensured that the images are correctly uploaded to the server.
I also made sure that the image styles are configured correctly.
Steps I have taken so far:

Verified that the images are uploaded to the correct directory
Checked file permissions to ensure the web server can access the images
Cleared the Drupal cache
Rebuilt the image styles

Despite these steps, the problem persists.

The web server is Hostinger, running on Linux. PHP version is 8.1.
Changing the image settings to display the original size instead of a 100x100 thumbnail does indeed seem to resolve the issue temporarily. However, I am looking for a solution that allows the thumbnails to display correctly at the specified size (100x100) rather than defaulting to the original size.
Any insights on how to ensure the thumbnails are generated and displayed properly at the desired dimensions would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in understanding if there's a configuration or caching issue within Drupal 10 that might be causing this problem.

Details: 


Would you please check your browser’s console log and report what it says?

404 console error:

Thank you for your input! Changing the image settings to display the original size instead of a 100x100 thumbnail does indeed seem to resolve the issue temporarily. However, I am looking for a solution that allows the thumbnails to display correctly at the specified size (100x100) rather than defaulting to the original size.

Would you please check your browser’s console log and report exactly what it says? Add that information to the Question or it will probably be closed. I did not suggest changing the image settings to the original.

Seems like your temp directory and files directory is not set properly. Check those directories permissions and configuration

Is nothing logged?

Just 404 error !

It would be nice to know the complete details like the URL of the 404.

I just refreshed the details in the question!

@miststudent2011 Done; i just try all the combinations also 777

@monalisa Just 404 error, i just refreshed the datails in the question.

No you did not!
